# Group indicator over my view contents

Tags: android

I have ben trying to play with expandablelistview. I used a relative layout for my group xml file and I set an image as align parent left (so the most left of the view).

However  I noticed that the group indicator arrow is on top of the image. For some reason I made the assumption that the group xml starts from the right of the arrow.

My question is, how can have the arrow indicator on the left of my view contents that  I populated in the XML

Thank you